# How certain arrays and array functions are handled under the hood in Excel; specifically the dependence of array handling on the calling function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In trying to systematically enumerate the possibilities when rolling four identical but loaded four-sided dice, I came across some unusual excel behavior.  Hoping someone can shed some light on what's going on under the hood.

The following table illustrates the possible rolls of a die:

1000 A

0100 B

0010 C

0001 D

each row is a possibility with a distinct probability.  In excel, this information can be made to occupy a 4x4 cell area--that is, the letter labels above are merely for convenience.

In trying to display all possible combinations of four rolls of such a die-- where the fist combination might be A + A + A + A or 4000, the second might be B + A + A + A or 3100, and so on for each of the 4^4=256 possibilities--I decided that I wanted to systematically offset A by 0,1,2, or 3 rows for each of four rolls then sum the results.  In other words, each possible group of 4 roles can be thought of as 4 copies of row A, each of which offset by some number of rows between 0 and 3, for example {0;0;0;0} or {1;0;0;0} in the first and second case enumerated directly above.

Oddly, though, I get the following.  (all formulas are array formulas keyed in with shift+ctrl+enter).

```
=TRANSPOSE(   SUM(   OFFSET(  A,  4x1ArrayOfRowOffsets,   0)))
```

displays the correct sum when entered into a 1x4 range.  Likewise if `=TRANSPOSE(...)` is replaced by `=INDEX(...,1,1)`.  I take it because both functions natively support array arguments.  However,

```
=SUM(   OFFSET(  A,  4x1ArrayOfRowOffsets,   0))
```

does not work--it seems that here the summation is conducted along the 4 rows returned by offset, each of which has value 1--it incorrectly displays only the value 1, even when evaluated in a multicell range as an array formula.  Oddly,

```
=SUM(   TRANSPOSE(   OFFSET(  A,  4x1ArrayOfRowOffsets,   0)))
```

does not work either--the transpose makes it so the summation is properly conducted along the columns returned by offset, but seems to throw out all but the first column.

Please note that, although the problem statement does not involve VBA, the lack of transparent array formula auditing in Excel proper (intermediate steps return #VALUE errors even when the final answer computes) likely means that, in order to investigate this problem, someone will have to write a bit of VBA that calls worksheet functions and manually outputs the intermediate calculations.  This is why I posed a version of this question, here.

Interweaving INDEX calls anywhere but the outside/first function call does not fix the problem.

To try and see what is going on, I investigated further.

```
=INDEX(   OFFSET(   A,   {w;x;y;z},   0),   1,   {1,2,3,4})
```

correctly displays the four rolls when entered into a 4x4 range.  As before w, x, y, and z are integers between 0 and 3 indicating row offsets from "A" in the table, above.  Furthermore,

```
=COLUMNS(   OFFSET(   A,   {w;x;y;z},   0))
```

returns the following when entered into a 5x5 range:

```
4   4   4   4   4

4   4   4   4   4

4   4   4   4   4

4   4   4   4   4

n/a n/a n/a n/a
```

All that is to say, calling `SUM(OFFSET(---))` with array arguments seems to produce varied output depending on what is doing the calling--specifically, whether or not the caller is a function which natively accepts proper array arguments.  Why is this?  What is actually going on, here?

Comment: It seems an interesting question, however, the lack of details that can be used to replicate the behavior claimed makes it difficult to provide an answer, please include enough details so the problem can be replicated and analyzed.

Comment: I provided the 4x4 matrix whose rows make up the arrays to be systematically added, as well as the exact function calls doing the adding.  Furthermore, I describe precisely the output in one case, and actually print the output in the other case discussed.  Please indicate exactly where your efforts to replicate the behavior are failing.